# Containerized NodeJS application on podman not reachable

Tags: node.js, networking, centos8, podman

I'm running a nodejs app in a pod (together with a mongo container)
Nodejs app listens on port 3000, which I expose from the container.
I have published port 3000 on the pod.
The container starts successfully (logs verified), but I can't reach my application on the host. When I curl to my app from within the pod it works.
Containers run rootfull, OS: CentOS Linux release 8.0.1905 (Core).
What am I missing?

```
curl http://localhost:3000
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 3000: No route to host
```

```
podman ps
CONTAINER ID  IMAGE                                                     COMMAND               CREATED         STATUS             PORTS                   NAMES
30da37306acf  registry.gitlab.com/xxx/switchboard:master  node main.js          34 minutes ago  Up 34 minutes ago  0.0.0.0:3000->3000/tcp  switchboard-app
acc08c71147b  docker.io/library/mongo:latest                            mongod                35 minutes ago  Up 35 minutes ago  0.0.0.0:3000->3000/tcp  switchboard-mongo
```

```
podman port switchboard-app
3000/tcp -> 0.0.0.0:3000
```

```
app.listen(3000, "0.0.0.0",function () {
  console.log('App is listening on port 3000!');
});
```

```
FROM node:13
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY /dist/apps/switchboard .
EXPOSE 3000
CMD [ "node", "main.js" ]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create production docker build, you can go another way. It's not a good idea to do npm install inside container, because it will be too large. Run  `npm run build` first, and then copy builded statics into docker container, created with nginx image.
So your Dockerfile shoud look  like:

```
FROM nginx:1.13.0-alpine
COPY build/*  /usr/share/nginx/html/
```

also specify exposed ports correctly with docker run. So, if you want expose 3000, your steps is:

```
cd /project/dir
docker build -t switchboard-app .
docker run -d -p 3000:80 --name switchboard-app switchboard-app
```